# Elm and VSCode: Formatter messes up spacing

Tags: elm, code-formatting

So I started learning Elm today. I use VSCode as my editor.

I followed [the docs](https://guide.elm-lang.org/install.html) for the set up and installed `elm` as well as `el-format` via `npm install -g elm elm-format`. I also installed the VSCode Elm extension.

Next, in my `settings.json` I set:

```
"[elm]": {
  "editor.formatOnSave": true
},
```

Then I went on with the tutorial. In it the code is formatted like this:

```
import Browser
import Html exposing (Html, Attribute, div, input, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)



-- MAIN


main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
  { content : String
  }


init : Model
init =
  { content = "" }



-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = Change String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
      { model | content = newContent }



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ input [ placeholder "Text to reverse", value model.content, onInput Change ] []
    , div [] [ text (String.reverse model.content) ]
    ]
```

But when I hit safe, it formats the code like this:

```
module Main exposing (Model, Msg(..), init, main, update, view)

import Browser
import Html exposing (Attribute, Html, div, input, text)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (onInput)



-- MAIN


main =
    Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }



-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { content : String
    }


init : Model
init =
    { content = "" }



-- UPDATE


type Msg
    = Change String


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        Change newContent ->
            { model | content = newContent }



-- VIEW


view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ input [ placeholder "Text to reverse", value model.content, onInput Change ] []
        , div [] [ text (String.reverse model.content) ]
        ]
```

So it adds extra lines, and extra `module Main exposing ...` and doubles the number of spaces. I tried setting spaces to 2 again using the footer in VSCode, but that didn't help.

My questions are:

1. Is it okay that saving adds the extra `module Main ...`?
2. Is having 2 spaces best practice / community standard, or 4?
3. If it is 2 (like it is in the tutorial's default code) how can I get my formatter to respect that?
4. If it is not, why has the tutorial the non-standard indentation?

Comment: to add, `elm-format` cannot be configured so that no one can argue about it. At first I thought this was stubborn, but now I really like it :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, this question is both too broad and primarily opinion-based and will probably be closed because of that. It would have been more suited for [the forums](https://discourse.elm-lang.org/) I think.

That said, I'm going to try to answer it as best as I can anyway, since it's here:

1. Yes? Most modules won't be very useful without exposing something and it's good practice to be explicit about what's being exposed.
2. `elm-format` *is* the community standard, so 4 it is.
3. You can't. This is by design. It has also been discussed to death in various fora. [Here's one issue discussing it](https://github.com/avh4/elm-format/issues/158)
4. You'd have to ask Evan about that. It might be related to formatting for the web, or just Evan being lazy.